# Switch activity on successful login from facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to login from facebook. It's successful but when I try to switch activity, it's not happening hare. It just shows the button with logout option.

Below is my code

```
    fbLogin=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    fbLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
    fbLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

            System.out.println("  accesstoken=  " + accessToken);
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                            try {
                                email1 = json.getString("email");

                                Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "email is" + email1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


            displayMessage(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Login Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Cannot connect.. Facebook error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and below is the function to switch activity

```
private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
    if(profile != null) {

        mail.setText(email1);
        session.createUserLoginSession(true, "FB");
        FGname=profile.getName();
        FGimage=String.valueOf(profile.getProfilePictureUri(100, 100));
        FGemail= email1;
        gv.setEmail(email1);

        Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "display profile executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new AsynDataClassFbGoogleLogin().execute();

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Also, when I start my application again, login has been done successfully.

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: @quicklearner sir problem is that login is success from facebook i am unable to switch activity.

Comment: call this  in  displayMessage(profile); in onCompleted

Comment: and post this method as well   new AsynDataClassFbGoogleLogin().execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Intent` to switch Activities:

```
 private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
if(profile != null) {

    mail.setText(email1);
    session.createUserLoginSession(true, "FB");
    FGname=profile.getName();
    FGimage=String.valueOf(profile.getProfilePictureUri(100, 100));
    FGemail= email1;
    gv.setEmail(email1);

    Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "display profile executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new AsynDataClassFbGoogleLogin().execute();

  //This code is what switches activities
  Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
}
else
{

}
```

}

You will also need to make sure that you add your new Activity to your manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".NewActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


        </activity>
```

You can read about activities here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add an intent to switch to another activity in onCompleted callback as follows :


GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                            try {
                                email1 = json.getString("email");

                                Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "email is" + email1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             // switch to another activity after successful login
                             Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
                             startActivity(intent);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```